# JavaScript onBlur for multiple fields

Tags: javascript

I have a table that consists of many text input fields which the user can assign values to. My goal is that if the user "onBlur"s ***any*** of the fields then a function will activate. I could resolve the issue by marking each cell individually, however it would be very repetitive and i'm sure there's a more efficient way around this.

To demonstrate:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>I</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Love</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stack Overflow</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With JS:

```
var e1 = document.getElementById('whatever1');
e1.onblur = alias;

function alias()  {
    alert('started');   
}
```

and then repeat this for each input box another 2 times. Or hopefully there's an easier way.

Comment: why not put the ids you want to add the handler to into an array, then iterate over that array and add the handler there.

Comment: Add a common class to all your element and use this for select all element [getElementByClassname][1]. if you want see exact what if your curent element add parameter `event` your function. and e.target give you DOM element.


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can delegate the event and put a listener on a containing element:

```
var e1 = document.getElementById('containing-table');
e1.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    alert(e.target);
}, true);
```

and the modified html:

```
<table id="containing-table">
  <tr>
    <td>I</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Love</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stack Overflow</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="whatever3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oj2wj1d6/7/

The advantage of this is that you can actually remove and add input elements and the listener will capture events on new nodes. You can add conditional statements inside of the function in `addEventListener` in order to further filter how you would want to respond to different types of event targets.

with jQuery, you could do something as simple as:

```
$("table").on("blur", "input", function(e){
    alert(e.target);
});
```

Some useful documentation to learn more:

- [The `blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur), scroll down for details about event delegation.
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [more about doing event delegation in vanilla JS](http://bdadam.com/blog/plain-javascript-event-delegation.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>I</td>
    <td><input class="blurMe" type="text" id="whatever1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Love</td>
    <td><input class="blurMe" type="text" id="whatever2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stack Overflow</td>
    <td><input class="blurMe" type="text" id="whatever3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then in javascript

```
//inputs as NodeList
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".blurMe");
//Convertion to Array
var inputsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(input);
// Loop to asign event
   inputsArr.forEach(function(item){
      item.onBlur = alias;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to all your element and use this for select all element [getElementByClassname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). if you want see exact what if your curent element add parameter `event` your function. and e.target give you DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```js
<script>
    document.getElementById()
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever');
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        arr[i].onblur=alias;
    }
function alias()  {
    alert('started');   
}
</script>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>I</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="whatever"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Love</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="whatever"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stack Overflow</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="whatever"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```